# Set custom Headers in shell.openExternal with Electron

Tags: javascript, shell, electron

As I couldn't find anything regarding this topic, I'll just ask straight away:

Is it possible to set custom headers while using electron.shell to open an external website? I need to set cookies for authentification, but I can't find any solution to this.

I couldn't find anything in the docs either, so I guess it's not possible, but I'd like to know for sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be whatever default browser the user is using? That makes it harder. E.g. if you know it is chrome you could make a custom user directory, with a pre-made cookie file, and tell chrome to use that. Firefox has something similar.

Comment: Yes, it has to be the default one, unfortunately.

Comment: My cookie is a sessionID which is received from a server through webview. I am able to get this ID, but I need to set them in another window. I wanted to use openExternal(), but I now use another electron-webview for it. Works, but isn't great, because I am now using open() on a new window and calling win.loadURL(url, {extraHeaders: "Cookies: ID"}) immediately after. Couldn't find antoher way to solve this issue.

Comment: @Faigjaz Did you manage to find a solution for this?